# Concatenation with addition in it doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, string, concatenation, addition

Here is my PHP code with SQL query, but the output isn't as expected:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `event_footers` (`event_id`, `order`, `file_id`, `url`) VALUES ';
foreach($all_footers as $key => $val){
    $sql .= '('.(int)$data['event_id'].', '.$key + 1 .', '.(int)$val['file_id'].', "'.addslashes($val['url']).'"), ';
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ', ');
var_dump($sql);
exit;
```

AND I get sql query like this:

```
`INSERT INTO `event_footers` (`event_id`, `order`, `file_id`, `url`) VALUES 1, 2135, "http://11.lt"), 1, 2136, "http://22.lt"), 1, 2140, "http://44.lt")`
```

Where is the first `(` after VALUES?

Comment: It's the `(int)` cast probably.

Comment: Why are you adding brackets in the loop? You don't want brackets around every value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` and `.` have the same [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), but are left associative. Means after the first concatenation:

```
'(' . (int)$data['event_id']
```

The string got added with your key, e.g.

```
"($data['event_id']" + $key
```

So the [string gets converted into an integer in that numerical context](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and *disappears*. To solve this use parentheses `()` around your addition.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the operator precedence. Try with -

```
$sql .= '(' 
           . ((int)$data['event_id']) . ', ' 
           . ($key + 1) . ', ' 
           . ((int)$val['file_id']) . ', "' 
           . addslashes($val['url']) . 
         '"), ';
```